# Powershell enable firewall rules - All File & Printer Sharing (where profile is private)

Tags: powershell, firewall

I'd like to know how to write a powershell script to enable inbound firewall on windows 7 for all File & Printer Sharing rules where profile is private.

I have already written scripts to insert additiontal rules, but don't know how to update built in rules.

Answer (score 5):

Not for Windows 7 sorry, but for anyone else that find this thread like me for looking for a way to enable file shares on a Windows Core server.

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name 'FPS-SMB-In-TCP' -Enabled True
```

got by looking at the results of

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*FPS*' } | Select-Object Name,Enabled,Direction
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `netsh` command to set firewall rules. Switch to `advfirewall firewall` context to set rules. The syntax is a bit different in Windows 7 than in XP, so watch out for older articles about `netsh` commands. Call netsh directly from Powershell, like any other program.

[Some](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709) [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about Netsh.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that when I get a chance and mark as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'Set-NetFirewallRule (identify your rule) -Enable True' to enable a rule. Need to put something to identify your rule, most like "-Name "

Comment: This only works for Windows 8 with PS v3.0, not for Windows 7.